# how to connect to multiple oracle databases of different servers via shell script

Tags: oracle

I want to connect to multiple (30) oracle databases which resides in different servers (27) via shell script and fetch details from each database. I have a user (test) created on all databases but the details I want to fetch needs sysdba privileges. In my environment, I cannot provide DBA privs to any other user due to limitations. Hence my idea is to connect to each database using sqlplus -s "$user/$password@$tnsentry" and then connect as sysdba to fetch details.

Though I am able to connect to all databases using test, the "connect as sysdba" is getting executed on current database in current server.

My script:

cat tmp/db.par | while read LINE
do
if [ -n "$LINE" ] ; then
tns_entry=$LINE
export tns_entry
sqlplus -s /nolog >> $tmp/query.log <
exit
sqlconn
fi
done

In the tns_entry loop, I have given ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO databases to get details from and I am running this query from a server where database XYZ resides. I didn't give XYZ in my loop and didn't connect to database but the query results are from XYZ database. Please help me on this.

Thank you!

Comment: use one database as a master, and creat links to the others.

Comment: You mean I need to register all databases in SQL Server and create linked servers? Or use DB links in Oracle? If it is to use db links, then as said above, i am already able to connect to database with test user without using links. I want the script to connect as sysdba to all databases.

Comment: cat /tmp/db.par | while read LINE  - db.par has all my db names
do  
if [ -n "$LINE" ] ; 
then tns_entry=$LINE 
export tns_entry 
sqlplus -s /nolog >> $TNS_ADMIN/user_management/user_creation.log <<sqlconn
connect $user_id/$user_pass@$tns_entry
select name,open_mode from v\$database;
conn /as sysdba
<my query>
exit
sqlconn
fi 
done

Comment: This is my script. Please suggest on how to connect to every database with sysdba.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect as sysdba

add "as sysdba" in the script and try.

> `conn sys/password@tnsentry as sysdba`